# Doubts about parameter in the URL

Tags: php, yii2

I have the following form to the address below:

`http://localhost/myapp/web/index.php?r=cashbook%2Faccomplishment`

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'accomplishment-form',
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
        'action' => Url::to(['/cashbook/accomplishment']),
                'method' => 'get',
]);
$form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(
                Category::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
                                ->orderBy("desc_category ASC")
                                ->all(), 'id_category', 'desc_category'),
                ['onchange'=>'this.form.submit()','prompt'=>'-- Select --']); 

ActiveForm::end();
```

Who processes and generates the following URL:

```
http://localhost/myapp/web/index.php?r=cashbook%2Faccomplishment&Cashbook%5Bcategory_id%5D=18
```

But I need only the **category_id** value (selected in dropDownList). That is, the URL should be:

```
http://localhost/myapp/web/index.php?r=cashbook%2Faccomplishment&category_id=19
```

How to stay that way or get just the **category_id**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view add `registerJs`:

```
$this->registerJs('var submit = function (val){
if (val > 0) {
    window.location.href = "' . Url::to(['/cashbook/accomplishment']) . '/?category_id=" + val;
}
}', View::POS_HEAD);
```

And not use `ActiveForm::begin...` and all your code. Instead of use this:

```
echo Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'id_category', ArrayHelper::map(
            Category::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
                            ->orderBy("desc_category ASC")
                            ->all(), 'id_category', 'desc_category'), ['onchange'=>'submit(this.value);','prompt'=>'-- Select --']);
```

Comment: Work when I changed from **/?category_id=** to **&category_id=**. Thank You Very Much